# Keyboard not showing up on iOS when focusing input element

Tags: javascript, html, ios, focus

I'm testing a webpage on iOS. I am trying to allow tab-like behavior when the user presses the `enter` key, so I've written some code to focus the next element when that happens.

I also have an element that, when focused, immediately focuses a child input element. When I focus this parent with my enter/tab simulation, it brings focus to the child, **but the keyboard does not show up**.

I can make the keyboard show up if I tap this child input. Moreover, if I use the real tab button to focus the parent, the keyboard shows up when focus is delegated to the child input. I have verified that the child input is indeed being focused by checking `document.activeElement`, and when I test on a computer I can type in the input without any additional clicks after focusing it with `enter`. The input is outlined in blue as well, so it is visibly focused.

And, lastly, this bug does not occur when the next element is directly an input. I press `enter` and the input receives focus and the keyboard shows up.

Is this an iOS bug? I've tested in both Safari and DuckDuckGo browsers. (I don't have a non-iPhone mobile device to test with to see if this is an issue with mobile devices in general.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setTimeout to delay the focus event. This will give iOS enough time to register the user action and show the keyboard.

```
function focusNextElement(currentElement) {
  const nextElement = currentElement.nextElementSibling;

  if (nextElement) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      nextElement.focus();
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

focusNextElement is a function that takes the current focused element as an argument. It finds the next sibling element and sets a timeout to focus it after a delay of 0 milliseconds & You can call this function when the enter key is pressed to focus the next element.